# Sub query like SQL in pyspark

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata, data-processing

I'm trying to do this kind of query:

```
SELECT age,COUNT(age)
   FROM T
   GROUP BY age
   HAVING age = MIN(SELECT COUNT(age) FROM T GROUP BY age)
   ODER BY COUNT(age)
```

I tried

```
min_size = df.groupBy("age").count().select(f.min("count"))
df.groupBy("age").count().sort("count").filter(f.col("count")==min_size).show()
```

but I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`

Is there any way to use subqueries in PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  your case, `min_size` is a DataFrame, not some integer.
Try to collect it into integer like this:

```
min_size = df.groupBy("age").count().select(f.min("count")).collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think there is a better way to make this query with pyspark?

Comment: @Axeltherabbit, well personally I would leave it as is - it's quite readable. And if you mean performance - well it's also so case-by-case, so easy to put a lot of effort in optimizing something and end up with overfitted solution. But, if you just want it in one line, here's one way you can do it: `df.groupBy("age").count().select(f.col("*"), f.min("count").over(Window.partitionBy()).alias("min_count")).filter("count=min_count").drop("min_count")`